# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{1}{2^x-5^x+3^x}}$. Why is my solution wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, indeterminate-forms

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to\infty}{\frac{1}{2^x-5^x+3^x}}. $$

My attempt:
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{2^x-5^x+3^x}}
= \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{2^x} \cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{5^x}{2^x}+\frac{3^x}{2^x}}} \\= \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{2^x} \cdot\frac{1}{\frac{1}{5^x}-\frac{5^x}{10^x}+\frac{3^x}{10^x}}\cdot\frac{1}{5^x}} = 0 
\cdot\infty \cdot 0 = 0.$$
Someone told me that it is a wrong way to show the limit. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Because $0\cdot\infty$ is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form)...?

Comment: You have problem when you go from limit expression to $0\cdot\infty\cdot 0$. This is not allowed via any theorem on limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $0\cdot \infty$ is an [Indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).
Note that
$${\frac{1}{2^x-5^x+3^x}}=\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^x\cdot \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^x-1+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x}.$$
Since $1/5$, $2/5$, and $3/5$ are positive numbers less than $1$, what may we conclude as $x\to +\infty$?

Comment: Obviously 0*(-1) = 0. I did not know about indetermined  form yet neither I had the idea of pull the $5^x$ out of the fracture. Thanks for fixing my issue.

Comment: @Maddude  Yes,  the idea here is to pull out the term that goes faster to infinity.

Comment: @user236182 Thanks for pointing out the typo!

Answer (score 4):

$0\cdot \infty$ is $inderterminate$. To see this, calculate the following limits:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \cdot x\qquad \text{and} \lim_{x\to \infty} 0\cdot x,$$
which are both of the form $0\cdot \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not true that $0\times\infty\times0=0$. In fact, $0\times\infty\times0$ is indeterminate.

Comment: Actually "$0\times\infty\times0$" is indeterminate, not "$0\times\infty\times0=0$".

Comment: @CiaPan Edited. Thanks.